# OpenSAML: Include X509 Certificate in EncyptedAssertion

Tags: saml-2.0, opensaml

I am trying to implement IDP initiated SSO using OpenSAML and ComponentSpace acts as SP. The SP is configured to accept a SAMLResponse's with an encrypted Assertion.

I am able to encryt the Assertion but the SP requires me to include X509 Certificate within KeyInfo in the EncryptedData.

Is this possible using OpenSAML?
If Yes, Could you please guide me on how to achieve this?

What SP Expects:

```
<saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <X509Data>
          <X509Certificate>......</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>......</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedKey>
  </KeyInfo>
  <CipherData>
    <CipherValue>......</CipherValue>
  </CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

What I am able to generate:

```
<EncryptedAssertion>
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
        <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey>
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>......</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </dsig:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>......</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</EncryptedAssertion>
```

Comment: Just to clarify the initial statement, ComponentSpace doesn't mandate the SAML assertion be encrypted. We support both plain text and encrypted SAML assertions. The encrypted assertion may have been a requirement of the organization acting as the service provider.

Answer (score 1):

Check the method signSamlResponseObject2() from http://ideone.com/p4Bhy9.

```
public void signSamlResponseObject2() {

        try {

            String keyStoreFileName = "/WEB-INF/classes/saml-data/keystore.jks";
            InputStream fis = getServletContext().getResource(keyStoreFileName)
                    .openStream();
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

            ks.load(fis, "abc123456*".toCharArray());
            fis.close();

            // Get Private Key Entry From keystore

            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks
                    .getEntry("zohosso", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(
                            "abc123456*".toCharArray()));

            PrivateKey privKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();

            PublicKey pubKey = ks.getCertificate("zohosso").getPublicKey();

            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks
                    .getCertificate("zohosso");

            /*
             * // Getting x509 Certificate from the keystore directly.
             * 
             * KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry certEntry =
             * (KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry) ks .getEntry("zohosso", new
             * KeyStore.PasswordProtection( "abc123456*".toCharArray()));
             * 
             * X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)
             * certEntry.getTrustedCertificate();
             */

            // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to generate
            // the
            // enveloped signature.

            // String providerName =
            // System.getProperty("jsr105Provider",JSR_105_PROVIDER);
            XMLSignatureFactory sigFactory = XMLSignatureFactory
                    .getInstance("DOM");

            // Create a Reference to the enveloped document (we are
            // signing the whole document, so a URI of "" signifies that) and
            // also specify the SHA1 digest algorithm and the ENVELOPED
            // Transform.

            List envelopedTransform = Collections.singletonList(sigFactory
                    .newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED,
                            (TransformParameterSpec) null));

            Reference ref = sigFactory.newReference("",
                    sigFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
                    envelopedTransform, null, null);

            SignatureMethod signatureMethod = sigFactory.newSignatureMethod(
                    SignatureMethod.DSA_SHA1, null);

            CanonicalizationMethod canonicalizationMethod = sigFactory
                    .newCanonicalizationMethod(
                            CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS,
                            (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null);

            // Create the SignedInfo
            SignedInfo signedInfo = sigFactory.newSignedInfo(
                    canonicalizationMethod, signatureMethod,
                    Collections.singletonList(ref));

            // Create a KeyValue containing the DSA PublicKey
            KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = sigFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
            KeyValue keyValuePair = keyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(pubKey);


            // Creating the x509 certificate data from Certificate object ( cert )

            List x509 = new ArrayList();

            x509.add(cert);

            X509Data x509Data = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509);

            // Create a KeyInfo and add the KeyValue to it
            // keyInfoItems.add(Collections.singletonList(keyValuePair));

            // Adding the certificate data and the key value pair to the keyInfo 


            List keyInfoItems = new ArrayList();

            keyInfoItems.add(x509Data);
            keyInfoItems.add(keyValuePair);

            KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(keyInfoItems);


            // Building the org.jdom.Document object from the samlResponse
            // string
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            org.jdom.Document doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    strResponseXML.getBytes()));
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------

            // Convert the rootElement extracted from the doc to w3cElement
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------

            org.jdom.Element docRootElement = doc.getRootElement();
            doc = docRootElement.getDocument();

            XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter();
            StringWriter elemStrWriter = new StringWriter();
            xmlOutputter.output(doc, elemStrWriter);
            byte[] xmlBytes = elemStrWriter.toString().getBytes();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            org.w3c.dom.Element w3cElement = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
                    .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlBytes))
                    .getDocumentElement();

            // --------------------------------------------------------------------

            // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the DSA PrivateKey and
            // location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element

            DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privKey, w3cElement);

            // compute the correct location to insert the signature xml
            // (location is important because the SAML xsd's enforce sequence on
            // signed
            // info.)

            org.w3c.dom.Node xmlSigInsertionPoint = null;

            String JSR_105_PROVIDER = "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI";
            String SAML_PROTOCOL_NS_URI_V20 = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol";

            org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList = w3cElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(
                    SAML_PROTOCOL_NS_URI_V20, "Extensions");
            if (nodeList.getLength() != 0) {
                xmlSigInsertionPoint = nodeList.item(nodeList.getLength() - 1);
            } else {
                nodeList = w3cElement.getElementsByTagNameNS(
                        SAML_PROTOCOL_NS_URI_V20, "Status");
                xmlSigInsertionPoint = nodeList.item(nodeList.getLength() - 1);
            }
            dsc.setNextSibling(xmlSigInsertionPoint);

            // Marshal, generate (and sign) the enveloped signature
            XMLSignature signature = sigFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo,
                    keyInfo);
            signature.sign(dsc);

            // Create the root dom element from the w3cElement using DOMBuilder
            DOMBuilder domBuilder = new DOMBuilder();
            org.jdom.Element signedElement = domBuilder.build(w3cElement);

            doc.setRootElement((org.jdom.Element) signedElement.detach());
            xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter();
            strFinalResponse = xmlOutputter.outputString(doc);

            System.out.println("The signed SAML Response is : "
                    + strFinalResponse);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Exception while attempting to sign the SAML Response.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Zeigeist, but Signing is working for me. I am facing issues in Encryption of the Assertion.